# Swift - view.endEditing in touchesBegan not working

Tags: swift

I try to hide keyboard by pressing on any place of the screen. I use following code

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)

}
```

But id doens't work, keyboard is not hiding.

How to use it correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Conform to `UITextFieldDelegate`
2. In your `viewController()` assign delegate of `YOURTextField.delegate = self`.
3. In your method use `self.YOURTextField.resignFirstResponder()`